# How to use try/catch to check for whether a number is within a range of 1-3? c#

Tags: c#

```
        /*Propmt user for beverages*/
        while (!bool_valid)
        {
            bool_valid = true;
            Console.WriteLine("Plesae Choose a Drink; Press 1 for Coke, Press 2 for Sprite, Press 3 for Dr.Prpper");
            try
            {
                int_bvg_type = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                (int_bvg_type > 0) && (int_bvg_type < 4);
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("PLease enter a Number between 1 and 3");
                bool_valid = false;
            }
        }
```

I need to make sure a numerical input, as a variable, is between 1 and 3 and was wondering how to do it with C# and `Try/Catch`. I tried `(int_bvg_type > 0) && (int_bvg_type < 4);`... but I get an error saying I cannot use it as a statement. Could someone please explain how to check to see if a number is between 1 and 3 using `Try/Catch`.

Comment: I dont think you want a try catch here, an if/else sounds like a better idea, try/catch should only be used for handling exceptional circumstances outside of your control

Comment: can I integrate the second line of the try in an if/else and then have that if/else aftet the Try/Catch?

Comment: @LukeMcGregor well the OP should probably catch FormatException and OverflowException which can be thrown

Comment: @ConradFrix good point thats a valid case for catching something here, he should still use an if for the actual range validation, or perhaps the default on a switch

Comment: You need to use "TryParse" ... this seems like a homework question.

Comment: Side note: PLease/Plesae (not sure why you have 2 strange spelling so offering both) avoid [Hungarian notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) in C# code. Advertisement: consider using IE10 that have [spell checking](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Browser/SpellChecking/) or Firefox or Chrome when composing the posts.

Answer (score 3):

You need a simple if statement.Not `try`/`catch`

```
if(!(beverageType > 0 && beverageType < 4))
{
   Console.WriteLine("Please enter a Number between 1 and 3");
}
```

Or if you insist about using `try/catch`:

```
if(!(beverageType > 0 && beverageType < 4))
{
   throw new FormatException("Please enter a Number between 1 and 3");
}
```

And catch your `FormatException`:

```
catch(FormatException ex) 
{ 
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: kinda a beginner here but what does the throw new FormatException line exactly do/how does it work?

Comment: it's creating and throwing a FormatException. You can read this documentation for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173163.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Try catch is not the recommended approach. Try catch is used for Exceptions. It will only work  if your program actually raises an exception.

My recommended approach would be the following:

```
if(!(int_bvg_type > 0 && int_bvg_type < 4))
{
   Console.WriteLine("PLease enter a Number between 1 and 3");
}
```

If you still want to do it via try catch then this would do the trick. But frankly, it's just stupid code:

```
    /*Propmt user for beverages*/
    while (!bool_valid)
    {
        bool_valid = true;
        Console.WriteLine("Plesae Choose a Drink; Press 1 for Coke, Press 2 for Sprite, Press 3 for Dr.Prpper");
        try
        {
            int_bvg_type = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            if(!(int_bvg_type > 0 && int_bvg_type < 4)){
                throw new Exception();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("PLease enter a Number between 1 and 3");
            bool_valid = false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a try/catch statement.

```
bool validInput = false;

while (!validInput)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please choose a Drink; Press 1 for Coke, Press 2 for Sprite, Press 3 for Dr.Prpper");

    int_bvg_type = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    if ((int_bvg_type > 0) && (int_bvg_type < 4))
        validInput = true;
}
```

You could also look into [`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if someone might enter a non-numeric character.

Answer (score 0):

Can i recommend the following as good structure:

```
while(true){
    try{
        Console.WriteLine("Please Choose a Drink; Press 1 for Coke, Press 2 for Sprite, Press 3 for Dr.Prpper");
        switch(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine())){
            case 1:
                //do coke
                break;
            case 2:
                //do sprite
                break;
            case 3:
                //do dr pepper
                break;
            default:
                //your message is shown if no matching rules were found, not based on a secondry range check
                Console.WriteLine("Im not sure what to do with that option");
                break;    
        }
    }
    //be explicit about the exceptions you want to catch
    catch(FormatException){
        Console.WriteLine("What you entered wasnt a number");
    }
}
```

Comment: +0: While valid this approach explicitly suggests to mix validation and handling of the data.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov thats exactly the point validation in this case is synonymous with handling of the data as it is checking the input matches the valid cases for handling. Single responsibility principal says you shouldn't double up on this logic as its used for exactly the same purpose

Comment: I'm not sure I buy SRP argument here - validate and process input seem to be 2 responsibilities for me (purely personal)... Maybe DRY would be more convincing. Again - this is my personal preference and your answer is fine for case where there is nothing else to validate before processing.

Answer (score 0):

> (int_bvg_type > 0) && (int_bvg_type < 4);

Your line is an expression, and it needs to be assigned to a variable, or evaluated, like in an if statement.

The try catch is not something you will need, as everyone has said, just use an if statement.